# How to write success statement in ajax jquery to change radiobuttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have first of all some html code with a few radio buttons with an attached span to each:

```
<div id="output2">
     <input type="radio" name="tid" value="1"><span class="green">Span 1</span>
                <input type="radio" name="tid" value="2"><span class="green">Span 2</span>
                <input type="radio" name="tid" value="3"><span class="green">Span 3</span>
                <input type="radio" name="tid" value="4"><span class="green">Span 4</span>
                <input type="radio" name="tid" value="5"><span class="green">Span 5</span>
```

I have an ajax request sending off a request to a php script the success part is empty here because this is where I have my problem.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
                            url: "fetch_time.php",
                            data: "datum_id=" + datum_id,                   
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $('#output2').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                            },
                            success: function(json) {   
        });
```

I get a return value from the php script in the form of a json file that looks for example like this:

```
[{"tid_id":"4"},{"tid_id":"5"}]
```

What I want to do is to use these values from the json file the 4 and 5 and compare them to the value of the radio buttons, and IF the value from the json file is the same as the value on that specific radiobutton I want the radiobutton to be disabled and the class of the corresponding span to change from class="green" to  class="red" OR just change visibility on the radiobutton and the span to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch_time.php",
    data: "datum_id=" + datum_id,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#output2').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
    },
    success: function (arrResponseData) {
        $.each(arrResponseData, function () {
            var intValue = this.tid_id;
            $("input:radio[value=" + intValue + "]")
                    .prop("disabled", true)
                    .children("span")
                    .prop("class", "red")

        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ali yes the basics work I have to change a few things to make it perfect for my conditions but you put the arrow in the right direction and I thank you for it however my reputation is not high enough yet to vote you up I only have 8 pts but it will get a vote as soon as I get my rep.

Comment: If it works as per your requirement then please up vote my answer.


Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need do something like this:

```
success: function(json) {
    var ids = [];

    json.forEach(function(i){
        ids.push(i.tid_id);
    });

    var $inputs = $('#output2 > input');
    $inputs.forEach(function(item){
        if(ids.indexOf(item.val()) >= 0) {
            item.addClass('red');
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show what it looked like when it was done it Works perfect now!!!

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "fetch_time.php",
                            data: "datum_id=" + datum_id,
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                             beforeSend: function() {
                             $("input:radio").prop("disabled", false)
                                             .next("span")
                                             .prop("class", "green");
                                                        },
                           success: function (arrResponseData) {
                                $.each(arrResponseData, function () {
                                    var intValue = this.tid_id;
                                    $("input:radio[value=" + intValue + "]")
                                            .prop("disabled", true)
                                            .next("span")
                                            .prop("class", "red");
```